# Why does text written to a file via StreamWriter not get saved when page is reloaded? (Xamarin)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, streamreader, streamwriter

I'm trying to write multiple strings to a txt file in order to save that information when the user switches pages. However, the strings seem to never be saved.

Entry. (source of strings to write to file)

```
<Entry 
x:Name="Entry"
Placeholder="Username"
WidthRequest = "200"
VerticalOptions = "Start"
HorizontalOptions = "Center"
/>
```

Code to write information to file.

```
        private void Write()
        {

            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path);
            sw.WriteLine(txtStorage.Length);

            //Writes length so that txtStorage can be correct length later

            sw.WriteLine(Entry.Text);

            //Writes username entered in this instance of the page

            for (int i = 0; i < txtStorage.Length; i++)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(txtStorage[i]);

                //Writes usernames stored from previous instances
            };
            sw.Close();
        }
```

Code to read file.

```
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);
            txtStorage = new string[Convert.ToInt32(sr.ReadLine())];

            //updates txtstorage to new length written in text file

            for (int i = 0; i < txtStorage.Length; i++)
            {
                txtStorage[i] = sr.ReadLine();
                //puts all usernames back into txtstorage
            };

            sr.Close();
        }
```

All usernames from previous instances are not saved. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if all you want to is pass data between pages this is a pretty cumbersome way to do it.  But the code you do have doesn't have the same logic for read and write - you write the actual length of the array first, but when you read it you are not treating that value as the length.

Comment: I'm not really trying to pass the data between pages, just trying to save it so that if they do switch pages, then come back, their usernames will not be gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you write the file, you are doing this

```
// 1. write the length of the array
sw.WriteLine(txtStorage.Length);

// 2. write the user name
sw.WriteLine(Entry.Text);

// 3. write the array
for (int i = 0; i < txtStorage.Length; i++)
```

this will generate a file something like this

```
3
myusername
user1
user2
user3
```

then when you read the file, you are doing this

```
// 1. read the length as a string
txtStorage = new string[Convert.ToInt32(sr.ReadLine())];

// 2. you aren't doing anything to handle line #2

// 3. you are using the LENGTH of txtstorage, which is 1, so your loop is only executing once
// and since you skipped #2, you are also starting on the wrong line
for (int i = 0; i < txtStorage.Length; i++)
```

instead, do this

```
// 1. read the length as an int
var ndx = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine());

// 2. read the user name
var user = sr.ReadLine();

// 3. use ndx as the loop counter, starting on the correct line
for (int i = 0; i < ndx; i++)
```